# Pixelated circles when scaling with SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The perimeter around a circle gets pixelated when scaling down the image.

The embedded circle image has a radius of 100 pixels. (The circle is white so click around the blank space, and you'll get the image.) Scaling down using SpriteKit causes the border to get very blurry and pixelated. How to scale up/down and preserve sharp borders in SpriteKit? The goal is to use a base image for a circle and create circle images of different sizes with this one base image.

[image: White circle]

```
    // Create dot
    let dot = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "dot50")

    // Position dot
    dot.position = scenePoint

    // Size dot
    let scale = radius / MasterDotRadius
    println("Dot size and scale: \(radius) and \(scale)")
    dot.setScale(scale)

    dot.texture!.filteringMode = .Nearest
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you should use `SKTextureFilteringLinear` instead of `SKTextureFilteringNearest`:

> SKTextureFilteringNearest:
>
> Each pixel is drawn using the nearest point in the texture. This mode
>   is faster, but the results are often pixelated.
>
> SKTextureFilteringLinear:
>
> Each pixel is drawn by using a linear filter of multiple texels in the
>   texture. This mode produces higher quality results but may be slower.

You can use SKShapeNode which will act better while scale animation, but end result (when dot is scaled to some value) will be almost pixelated as when using SKSpriteNode and image.

Comment: This is the default filtering mode and it's also pixelated. .Nearest was only tried after .Linear proved blurry.

Comment: You should be aware that when scaling a bitmap you will always get artefacts in some percent. Maybe you could try with SKShapeNode, but I don't like them personally because those cannot be drawn in single draw call like SKSpriteNode-s.

Comment: If you are not satisfied with .Linear filtering mode I am afraid I am out ideas. When downscaling I am always ready for some quality loss. Because of that I do it just for fast animations. Also never noticed some huge difference. I am just wondering how much is pixelation noticeable when you consider it as problematic.